What is the correct use of await using FlutterSecureStorage?
I'm writing a flutter app that interacts with some API, the first time I log in, the backend returns me a token that I save in SecureStorage. Then for each call I pass it in the header. To recover it from storage I do this:
String token = await SecureStorage.getToken();
class SecureStorage {
 static const _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

 static Future<String> getToken() async {
   String token = await _storage.read(key: "authToken") ?? "";
   return token;
 }

static Future<bool> setToken(String authToken) async {
   await _storage.write(key: "authToken", value: authToken);
   return true;
 }
}

It has always worked, however once I put the app on testflight, we noticed that sometimes it happens that the token cannot be retrieved and therefore it is passed as empty. It seems like a question of timing. However I don't understand why since I use await.
What is the problem?

It depends on the code that calls getToken and setToken.

@trincot as I wrote in the question.
I simply call it like this: String token = await SecureStorage.getToken();

Yes, but it depends on the combination of reading and writing code. If you read before the write action is completed, there could be an issue. await is no guarantee if the async function in which it occurs is not awaited. I cannot tell that from what you have shared.

You're likely getting an empty value because the authToken key is missing from storage. In this line: String token = await _storage.read(key: "authToken") ?? ""  This could be because it hasn't been set yet, or it might have been lost. The problem lies elsewhere, not with async-await
